# Extracting specific files from a jar using regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I have a config jar that contains files like below in its resources directory. The names are in the format `<text>-<text>.properties` or `<text>-<text>-<alphanumeric>.properties`

```
abb-servicea.properties
abb-servicea-dev1.properties
abb-serviceb-dev2.properties
abb-servicea-prod.properties
abb-serviceb.properties
```

I need to extract only the below files from the jar

```
abb-servicea.properties 
abb-serviceb.properties
```

I've tried `unzip abb-configs.jar abb-*[a-z].properties`. I'm unable to specifically pick only `abb-servicea.properties` and `abb-serviceb.properties`. It ends up showing `abb-servicea-prod.properties` also

```
abb-servicea.properties
abb-serviceb.properties 
abb-servicea-prod.properties
```

How can I extract files with the pattern `abb-<servicename>.properties`?

**Edit:** Note that the property names could be any `abb-<anyservicename>.properties`. For e.g.: it could be `abb-serviceb.properties`. So essentially it should extract the files as

```
abb-servicea.properties 
abb-serviceb.properties
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
bsdtar --exclude='*-*-*' -xf abb-configs.jar 'abb-*.properties'
```

To extract the `abb-*.properties` except those that contain two `-`s.

To use a regexp:

```
bsdtar -'s/^abb-[[:alpha:]]*\.properties$/~/' -'s/.*//' -xf abb-configs.jar
```

Where the first `-s`, does a noop substitution (`~` is the equivalent of `&` in `sed`'s `s`) for the archive members we want to extract, and the second deletes the ones we don't want (that haven't been matched by the first one) so we end up extracting the archive members whose name matches the `^abb-[[:alpha:]]*\.properties$` regex.

`[[:alpha:]]*` matches any sequence of 0 or more alphas. You could also use `[^-]*` for sequences of characters other than `-`. Replace `*` with `\{1,\}` for "1 or more" instead of "0 or more".

---

In your:

> ```
> unzip abb-configs.jar abb-*[a-z].properties
> ```

First note that the `*` and `[a-z]` should be quoted as those are shell globbing operators:

```
unzip abb-configs.jar 'abb-*[a-z].properties'
```

(here quoting the whole argument).

`unzip` treats the pattern as a (basic) shell wildcard pattern, not as a regular expression.

In shell wildcards, `*` stands for any number of characters (like `.*` in regex). So here, it matches on `abb-servicea-prod.service` because `*` matches on `servicea-pro` and `[a-z]` on `d`.

Some shells have advanced wildcard operators that can match on one or more alphas like the `[[:alpha:]]+` of extended regexps or the `[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}` of basic regexps. That includes ksh's `+([[:alpha:]])` (also supported by `bash -O extglob`) and `zsh -o extendedglob`'s `[[:alpha:]]##`, but those are not supported by `unzip`.

You could still use your shell's wildcard patterns though by doing (here in `zsh` as an example):

```
set -o extendedglob
members=( ${(f)"$(bsdtar tf abb-configs.jar)"} )
wanted=( ${(M)members:#abb-[[:alpha:]]##.properties} )
(( $#wanted )) && print -rNC1 -- $wanted |
  bsdtar --null -T /dev/stdin -nxf abb-configs.jar
```

Or do the regexp matching with `grep` (and any shell):

```
bsdtar tf abb-configs.jar |
  grep -xE 'abb-[[:alpha:]]+\.properties' |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  bsdtar --null -T /dev/stdin -nxf abb-configs.jar
```

See these [two](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1733) [issues](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1734) with current versions of `bsdtar` for hints at potential problems if using that approach for other patterns.

---

`bsdtar` is the `tar`-like CLI interface to the `libarchive` library that can manipulate dozens of different archive formats, so is the one command you generally want to use if possible to deal with archives as then you can use the same API for all archive formats.

If you don't have and can't install `bsdtar`, but you have Info-ZIP's `unzip` command which can only deal with ZIP files (and `jar` files happen to be such files), you could do the same (assuming GNU `xargs`) with:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a <(
    unzip -Z1 abb-configs.jar |
      grep -xE 'abb-[[:alpha:]]+\.properties'
  ) unzip -q abb-configs.jar
```

(`unzip` also treats arguments as wildcard patterns, not a problem here as the ones we select don't contain wildcard characters).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Unfortunately, my version of RHEL does not have bsdtar. I am working in a restricted environment and cannot get it installed.

Comment: @vermachint, see edit.